# MongoDB presplitting chunks for compound shard key

Tags: mongodb, sharding

In my mongodb setup I have a compound shard key `{"region" : 1, "foo" : 1, "bar" : 1}` and I know the values region can be and that each region should be on one chunk.

Therefore I'd like to pre-split based on the region key only. The sharding status should look like that afterwards:

```
{ "region": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "foo": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar": { "$minKey" : 1 } } -> { "region": region1, "foo": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar": { "$minKey" : 1 } } on: shard1
{ "region": region1, "foo": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar": { "$minKey" : 1 } } -> { "region": region2, "foo": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar": { "$minKey" : 1 } } on: shard2
{ "region": region2, "foo": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar": { "$minKey" : 1 } } -> { "region": { "$maxKey" : 1 }, "foo": { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar": { "$minKey" : 1 } } on: shard3
```

I've tried some ways to achieve that, but nothing worked:

- `db.runCommand( { split : "mydb.mycollection" , middle : { "region" : "region1" } } );` will return an error, because the complete shard key have to be part of the split.
- `db.runCommand( { split : "mydb.mycollection" , middle : { "region" : "region1", "foo" : { "$minKey" : 1 }, "bar" : { "$minKey" : 1 } } } );` and `db.runCommand( { split : "mydb.mycollection" , middle : { "region" : "region1", "foo" : "$minKey" , "bar" : "$minKey" } } );` will interpret the minKey as String and split on that base which is wrong.

How can I finally split chunks with a compound shard key on a single field base?!

Cheers.

Comment: Really this is for dba exchange, it is off topic here

Comment: Thanks Sammaye, I wasn't aware of the dba exchange. I'll close this question and already opened this in the dba area. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/68487/mongodb-presplitting-chunks-for-compound-shard-key